# WordPress WooCommerce automatic feed download

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce, feed

I want add to my e-shop an automatic feed download (from URL). Is there a plugin for that? Thanks

Comment: Do you want an XML feed of your current products, or what exactly do you want?

Comment: You can download woocommerce product feed using this free [woocommerce product feed plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write php script, which will fetch data from DB and print them to your format (XML, CSV or something like this) with defined header. But you must do it in correct format.

After you do it, you can access to feed via url (http://yourDomain/yourScript.php) or you can automate this with CRON job.

If you don't have basic experiences in PHP to write this you can do it via plugin. You can choose from these:
[WooCommerce Feed plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=woocommerce%20feed)